# Break Text automaticly, justification behind username?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following problem:

When the text I wrote is to long for the DIV, it breaks at unpleasant places, how do I set it at where to break?

Long text: **Test: Hello My Name Is Tim4497**

But it breaks after "Test:" so it looks like below:

**Test:**

**Hello My Name Is Ti**

Do you know how to make it look like:

**Test: Hello My Name**

**is Tim4497.**

after the line break, it has to line up after "Test:"

Also, if it breaks into multiple lines, the line spaces must be the same.

So far this is what I have but doesn't do what I wanted.

HTML-Code:

```
<div>
 <span class="user_name" style="color:#FF7000">Test</span>
 ": "
 <span class="user_message">Hello my name ist Tim and my english is terrible.</span>
</div>
```

How to solve this problem with JS or Html/CSS?

Thank you :),

tim4497

Comment: For example see the related on the right -> the Number is the username and the title is the textmessage

Comment: It’s not clear at all what you are asking, and the code posted does not reproduce the issue described in the text. Texts are not arbitrarily cut unless you have some code that causes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it... Perhaps one of the cleanest would be through css `table` and `table-cell`. This will place your elements side-by-side perfectly.

Make your wrapper div a `display: table` and your spans `display: table-cell`. (don't forget to put your ":" inside a span too, for better visual)

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <span class="user_name" style="color:#FF7000">Test</span>
     <span>:</span>
     <span class="user_message">Hello my name ist Tim and my english is terrible.</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
}

.wrapper span {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jy7d431p/1/ - Resize the screen and see, or set a width to the last span...

Comment: Thank you so much I love u :D i added: .user_message {text-align: justify} like JDB said and its perfect!! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use floated DIV's to achieve something like this effect:

```
<div style="width: 200px; background: blue;">
    <div style="float:left; background: red;">Name:</div>
    <div style="float:left; text-align: justify; background: green; width: 100px;">Some extremely long text would go in here that should wrap around several times and be flush with the first and last charcters.</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Floating can be a complicated topic if you don't know much about it, though. See [All About Floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) from css-tricks.com.

http://jsfiddle.net/eezpzj0L/

Comment: Thank you too, see the LcSalazar Comment, the text-align justify was the tip to complete his Idea :)